# ffmpeg concat with different codecs in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

i'm working on a videopipeline project and try to add some stuff for it.
Atm it's running fine until the code reach this point:

```
os.system('ffmpeg -i ' + self._rendition + ' -i ' + self._outChunk + ' -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[outv]" ' + self._tempRenditon)
```

There is no error message or anything else. It is used to link individual chunks with different codec parameters. After this line it's just telling me that it cant find `self._tempRendition`.

Did i made an mistake with the `os.system` call?

thx and greetz

Comment: Print your command and try to run it in shell directly. It's probably ffmpeg not doing what you are looking for and not creating file.

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to this:

`os.system('ffmpeg -i ' + rendition + ' -i ' + outChunk + ' -filter_complex "[0:v:0][1:v:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[outv]" -map "[outv]" ' + tempRenditon)`

and now it's working as expected!!!

thx @Calumah